# NSPredicate to compare integer using Contains

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nspredicate

I am using a NSPredicate to search numbers in the list using UISearchBar ,
it works in case of strings but does not work for an integer

I am using the following predicate

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ contains[c]  %d", @"number", [searchBar.text intValue]]];
[objectArray filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
[tableview reloadData];
```

FOR example if I type 1 then all the ones in the array must be listed, I have tried == it works only for the exact number if tried any work around for this any body?

Now I get an error if I use this method "Can't use in/contains operator with collection"

Comment: what is "number"?  Is that a key in a dictionary?

Comment: number is one of the property of my custom class called student which has two properties int number and NSString *name

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think this predicate should work for you:

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.number.stringValue CONTAINS %@",searchBar.text];
```

After thinking about this, I'm not sure why self.number.stringValue works, but it did when I tested it (self.number is an int). Not sure why I can send stringValue to an int?

Comment: Predicates use key-value coding to obtain their values and key-value coding always promotes properties to objects even if they're just atomic C values.

Answer (score -1):

Predicates can be tricky to work with, so perhaps an alternative would work for you:

```
NSInteger index = 0;
while (index < objectArray.count)
{
    NSString *currentString = [objectArray objectAtIndex:index];
    if ([currentString rangeOfString:searchBar.text].length == 0)
    {
        [objectArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
        continue;
    }
    index++;
}
```

Here, any strings in your array that do not contain your searchBar text will be removed.